# Countries "of the world" or "in the world"

Tags: prepositions

How should I say:

> There are many threats faced by almost all countries IN the world

or

> There are many threats faced by almost all countries OF the world

I used to say "IN the world". However, I have seen both of the cases on the Internet.

Comment: Related: *[“Highest building of/in the world”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49770)*

Comment: Yes, already checked that question.

Comment: To use "of" would have a slightly more literary feel to it. Usually one would say "in" there.

Comment: And just to be complete, if you replace _world_ with _Earth_, the preposition changes to _on_.

Comment: Why is it necessary to say either? Where else are the countries going to be? Thinking about the phrase "Workers of the World, Unite!" the "of the world" emphasises across international boundaries but when talking about different countries that is already a given.

Comment: As noted by @MartinSmith, the words after "countries" are redundant and sound clumsy.  If you were writing this for a newspaper article or a book, the editor would almost certainly strike out the redundant words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, *of* is the more used collocation in the construction *all countries of/in the world.* Have a look at this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=all+countries+of+the+world%2Call+countries+in+the+world&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Call%20countries%20of%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Call%20countries%20in%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0). This might be based in the fact that *of the world* regardless of what it follows is already more idiomatic as *in the world.* ([Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*+the+world&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%2A%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bof%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bin%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bto%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ball%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Binto%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Band%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthat%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfrom%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bover%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthroughout%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0))

It seems however, that the usage of *in* gains favor if whatever is referred is more tangible. In this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*+of+the+world%2C+*+in+the+world&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%2A%20of%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bparts%20of%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpart%20of%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brest%20of%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bend%20of%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhistory%20of%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnations%20of%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bman%20of%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bout%20of%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bknowledge%20of%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcreation%20of%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2C%2A%20in%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bthing%20in%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcountry%20in%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpeople%20in%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bman%20in%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bplace%20in%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Belse%20in%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnothing%20in%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmen%20in%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthings%20in%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnation%20in%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0) country and nation in singular usage, places an people are used with *in* while more abstract concepts like *part(s), rest, end, knowledge, history and creation* are using *of.*

Answer (score 1):

When the sentence starts with "There is/are", my preference is "in the world". Otherwise, "of the world" will be my choice.